# how to act on a file when it begins to exist with autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I've got the following bit of code, which should work as far as I know.  The goal is to continually check for the existence of Z:\auto_run.txt.  Once it exists, each line of the file (being a path to a file), should be opened in notepad++. Finally, delete Z:\auto_run.txt.

The last bit I have gotten to work independently.  The question is how to continually check for the file's existence?  When I run the below code in a standard Autohotkey.ahk, it does not seem to work, and even when the file exists, nothing happens.

```
IfExist, Z:\auto_run.txt
{
    Loop, read, Z:\auto_run.txt
    {
        IfExist, Z:\%A_LoopReadLine%
            Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe Z:\%A_LoopReadLine%
    }
    FileDelete, Z:\autohotkey\auto_run.txt
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would putting the whole thing in a loop work?

```
Loop
{
    IfExist, Z:\auto_run.txt
    {
        Loop, read, Z:\auto_run.txt
        {
            IfExist, Z:\%A_LoopReadLine%
                Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe Z:\%A_LoopReadLine%
        }
        FileDelete, Z:\autohotkey\auto_run.txt
    }

    Sleep, 100 ; Short sleep
}
```

If you don't want to lock the scrip to the loop you can use a timer as well.

```
#Persistent

fullFilePath := "Path\To\File.txt"
SetTimer, CheckForFile, 500
return

CheckForFile:
    if (FileExist(fullFilePath)) {
        ; Do something with the file...
        Loop, Read, %fullFilePath%
        {
            MsgBox % A_LoopReadLine
        }

        ; Delete the file
        FileDelete, %fullFilePath%
    }
return
```

Comment: Interesting, so the first solution works when put in its own file, but the second does not.  I kind of like the elegance of just one .ahk file running, with all of my stuff in it, so I'd like to get the second solution to work. Out of curiosity, did you test it yourself?
EDIT: Also just realized the first solution doesn't work every time! about 1 out of every 3 times or so, it works...

Comment: @brollin I think the second solution was missing `#Persistent`. I've updated it now with a version that works on my machine. Just make sure your `SetTimer` call is made in the auto-exec section of the script. Meaning above the first `return` statement. As for why it would sporadically fail to work I'm not sure. It could be that the file you're trying to delete is locked by some other program, if that's the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the rescinding of the answer... it still doesn't work :'( I included #Persistent and changed the other details of your second solution to no avail :/
My other stuff at the top is:
#SingleInstance force
#HotkeyInterval 100
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 20
Could any of that be the issue?

Comment: @brollin Not really. What part of the intended behavior doesn't work? Also, have you tried putting the second script in its own file? It could be something else in your script interfering, hard to say without seeing it.